# Need help finding error in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I cant seem to get the stored procedure code to execute without errors such as:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure task5proc, Line 37 [Batch Start Line 37]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure task5proc, Line 40 [Batch Start Line 37]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure task5proc, Line 71 [Batch Start Line 37]
> Incorrect syntax near '('

Code from here:

```
create table dbo.task5
(
    id int identity, 
    col1 varchar(10), 
    col2 varchar(10), 
    col3 varchar(10), 
    col4 varchar(10), 
    maincolumn varchar(50)
)

insert into task5
values (null, null, null, null, '1-AS,2-34,3-DF,4-fG'),
       (null, null, null, null, '3-AS,4-fG'), 
       (null, null, null, null, '1-sd,3-df,4-ds'), 
       (null, null, null, null, '1-25,2-ww,3-d,4-ss'),
       (null, null, null, null, '1-sd,2-AS,4-fG')

select * from dbo.task5
go

create or alter proc dbo.task5proc (@maxcount int)
as
begin
    declare @counter int, @var varchar(50)
    set @counter = 1
    set @var = (select maincolumn from dbo.task5 where id = @counter)

    declare @give1 varchar(10), @give2 varchar(10), @give3 varchar(10), @give4 varchar(10)

    while @counter <= @maxcount
    begin
        begin
            if charindex('1-', @var , 1) = 0
                set @give1 = 'N/P'
            else
                set @give1 = SUBSTRING(@var , charindex('1-', @var , 1)+2, charindex(',', @var , 1)-3)
        end

    begin
        if (charindex('2-', @var , 1)) !=0 and charindex('1-', @var , 1) != 0
            set @give2 = substring(@var, (charindex('2-', @var , 1)+2), (charindex(',', @var, charindex(',', @var,1)+1))-(charindex('2-', @var , 1)+2))

        else if (charindex('2-', @var , 1)) !=0 and charindex('1-', @var , 1) = 0
            set @give2 = SUBSTRING(@var , charindex('2-', @var , 1)+2, charindex(',', @var , 1)-3)

        else
            set @give2 = 'N/P'
    end

    begin
        if (charindex('3-', @var,1)) != 0 and (charindex('2-', @var , 1)) !=0 and charindex('1-', @var , 1) != 0
            set @give3 = substring(@var, (charindex('3-', @var,1)+2), charindex(',', @var,charindex(',', @var,(charindex(',',@var,1) +1)) +1) - (charindex('3-', @var,1)+2))

        else if (charindex('3-', @var,1)) != 0 and (charindex('2-', @var , 1)) !=0 and charindex('1-', @var , 1) = 0
            set @give3 = substring(@var, (charindex('3-', @var , 1)+2), (charindex(',', @var, charindex(',', @var,1)+1))-(charindex('2-', @var , 1)+2))

        else if (charindex('3-', @var,1)) != 0 and (charindex('1-', @var , 1)) !=0 and and charindex('2-', @var , 1) = 0
            set @give3 = substring(@var, (charindex('3-', @var , 1)+2), (charindex(',', @var, charindex(',', @var,1)+1))-(charindex('1-', @var , 1)+2))

        else
            set @give3 = 'N/P'
    end

    begin
        if (charindex('4-', @var,1)) != 0 and (charindex('3-', @var,1)) != 0 and (charindex('2-', @var , 1)) !=0 and charindex('1-', @var , 1) != 0
            set @give4 = right(@var, (charindex('4-', @var, 1) + 2) - charindex(',', @var,charindex(',', @var,(charindex(',',@var,1) +1)) +1))

        else if (charindex('4-', @var,1)) != 0 and (charindex('3-', @var , 1)) = 0 and charindex('2-', @var , 1) != 0 and charindex('1-',  @var , 1) != 0
            set @give4 = right(@var, (charindex('4-', @var, 1) + 2) - charindex(',', @var,(charindex(',',@var,1) +1)))

        else if (charindex('4-', @var,1)) != 0 and (charindex('2-', @var , 1)) =0 and charindex('1-', @var , 1) != 0 and charindex('3-', @var , 1) != 0
            set @give4 = right(@var, (charindex('4-', @var, 1) + 2) - charindex(',', @var,(charindex(',',@var,1) +1)))
    
        else if (charindex('4-', @var,1)) != 0 and (charindex('2-', @var , 1)) !=0 and charindex('1-', @var , 1) = 0 and charindex('3-', @var , 1) != 0
            set @give4 = right(@var, (charindex('4-', @var, 1) + 2) - charindex(',', @var,(charindex(',',@var,1) +1)))

        else if (charindex('4-', @var,1)) != 0 and (charindex('3-', @var , 1)) !=0 and charindex('2-', @var , 1) = 0 and charindex('1-', @var , 1) = 0
            set @give4 = right(@var, (charindex('4-', @var, 1) + 2) - (charindex(',',@var,1) +1))

        else if (charindex('4-', @var,1)) != 0 and (charindex('3-', @var , 1)) =0 and charindex('2-', @var , 1) != 0 and charindex('1-', @var , 1) = 0
            set @give4 = right(@var, (charindex('4-', @var, 1) + 2) - (charindex(',',@var,1) +1))

        else if (charindex('4-', @var,1)) != 0 and (charindex('3-', @var , 1)) =0 and charindex('2-', @var , 1) = 0 and charindex('1-', @var , 1) != 0
            set @give4 = right(@var, (charindex('4-', @var, 1) + 2) - (charindex(',',@var,1) +1))

        else
            set @give4= 'N/P'
    end

    update task5(col1, col2, col3, col4)
    set col1 = @give1, col2 = @give2, col3 = @give3, col4 = @give4
    where id = @counter

    set @counter = @counter + 1
    set @var = (select maincolumn from dbo.task5 where id = @counter)
end
end

go

exec task5proc(select count(*) from dbo.task5)
```

Comment: The error say `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'.`  You should do a search for the word `and` in your code, you will surely spot the mistake.  Also you cannot execute the stored procedure like that. Do refer to documentation when you are in doubt

Comment: For starters, your `UPDATE` statement is all wrong - other than with the `INSERT`, you **must not** specify the list of columns in the `UPDATE tableName SET .....` statement

Comment: its in your best interest to do research of your own before asking for help.  https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-stored-procedures-for-beginners/

Comment: Tip: When faced with mind numbing code that won't compile try a brute force attack. Delete one of the `begin`/`end` blocks and do a Parse Query (Ctrl+F5) in SSMS. If that "fixed" the problem then have a close look at the block of code you removed, otherwise replace that block and delete another. Asides: Reinventing a `cursor` is bad. Assuming that `Id` values are dense, i.e. no values skipped, is bad. Computing common expressions once and reusing the results is good.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have any intelliSense?
On row 57 you have a double `and`:

```
else if (charindex('3-', @var,1)) != 0 
and (charindex('1-', @var , 1)) !=0 
and and /*<--- THIS WONT WORK*/ charindex('2-', @var , 1) = 0
    set @give3 = substring(@var, (charindex('3-', @var , 1)+2), (charindex(',', @var, charindex(',', @var,1)+1))-(charindex('1-', @var , 1)+2))
```